# Get most recent records where one field is not null

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm looking to narrow down my database to have only the most records. The most recent records need to have a value in a specific field.

```
ID  Account_nbr Date    Name
1   622     7/10/2018   Stu
2   622     7/24/2018   
3   151     7/18/2018   Taylor
4   151     7/24/2018   Taylor
```

This is an example of the database.
I want the code to do this:

```
ID  Account_nbr Date    Name
1   622     7/10/2018   Stu
4   151     7/24/2018   Taylor
```

I have tried the following code:

```
Select m.*
FROM [table] m
 INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT last(Date) as LatestDate
,account_nbr
FROM [table]
WHERE Name IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY account_nbr
) b 
ON m.Date = b.LatestDate
AND m.account_nbr = b.account_nbr
```

The output only included the most recent date and did not take into account records that were null in the name field.

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server,` etc..) that you are using.

Comment: which DBMS sql server, oracle etc?  are windowed functions and Common Table Expressions available?

Answer (score 1):

I would do :

```
select t.*
from table as t
where t.name is not null and
      t.date = (select max(t1.date)
                from table as t1
                where t1.account_nbr = t.account_nbr
               );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select 
    m.*
From 
    [table] As m
Where
    m.[Date] In
        (Select Max([Date])
        From [table] As T
        Where T.[Name] Is Not Null 
            And T.account_nbr = m.account_nbr)
```